# How to expose web application on Docker Desktop / Minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, docker-desktop

I deployed simple .NET Core application consisting of 3 pods using Docker Desktop with Kubernetes.
My goals is to expose working web application in my host browser:

[image]

My React Application in Fronend pod points in appsettings.js file to Backend Cluster IP Service to fetch data from backend. When im inside the Frontend pod this works normally, fetch works.

Exposed Fronend Pod using NodePort Service, application is accessible but my problem is with failing requests to Backend pod - requests are pointing to Backend ClusterIP service and my host machine cannot resolve them.

How this should be done on single node environment like Docker Desktop or Minikube?
It also should work if I would like to use multiple different backend apis in my frontend app.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, both Frontend and Backend need to be accessible from outside the cluster. So the Backend service must be of type `NodePort` or `LoadBalancer`.

The reason is that the Frontend does not interact with the Backend Service (in the cluster). The Frontend pod is just used by the browser to download your React application. Then the browser runs your React application. And this application - **that does not run in your cluster** - must consume the Backend Service. That is why the Backend Service must be externally accessible.

Comment: Thanks for answer! I already check and it works with backend services exposed through NodePort. But is there a better way of doing this? I.e. in frontend application I need to specify exposed backend service address as localhost:NodePort. Same with accessing frontend application, localhost:NodePort. Can I expose them in more descriptive way? I.e to specify backend service in configuration as backend-api instead of localhost:NodePort. Can I acheive this with Ingress Controller?

Comment: You can create a load balancer service (instead of nodeport). Then in minikube, you will have to run the command minikube service service-name. This will allocate an IP to the service named "service-name". Finally, you can obtain this IP with kubectl get services. And updates your code to call the service with IP:PORT.

Comment: And if you need URIs, you will have to install an ingress controller to handle this. Check this article that demonstrate how to use traefik with minikube: https://medium.com/kubernetes-tutorials/deploying-traefik-as-ingress-controller-for-your-kubernetes-cluster-b03a0672ae0c

Answer (score 1):

For me easiest way was to use minikube with Ingress Controller -
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/